# Ruby - Map characters to integers in 2d array

Tags: ruby, arrays, dictionary

I have a problem I can't for the life of me solve. I'm writing a Ruby app (I've been a PHP developer for 8 years, just starting with Ruby) that sells tickets for a concert hall. Each seat has a row (a...z) and a number (1...x). The database model has row (string) and num (int) for each seat.

How can I convert my array of seats from the database into a 2d array? For example, seat A1 would go into seat[1][1] = "value"; seat C4 would map to seat[3][4] = value. The issue is converting the row string to Ascii and subtracting the offset? Or is there an easier way?

Many thanks

Comment: Why convert the row to an integer?  You can just put the string in there instead.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Not sure I get you? If I try and do seats[seat.row][seat.num] = value I get a TypeError can't convert String into Integer. Therefore I assumed arrays were only indexed by integer, so conversion was necessary?

Comment: @Dan: Ruby has Hashes, which are much the same as PHP's associative arrays.  They are indexed the same way as arrays (see my answer), but an empty hash is represented as {} instead of [].

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is probably to use a hash instead.  For example: `seat['A'][1] = value`

But if you really need an array for some reason, then the method you describe is the simplest.  Assuming the row string is a single character 'A' through 'Z', you can do it using `row_string[0] - ?A` (or `row_string[0] - ?A + 1` if you want the index starting at 1 as in your example).  For a multi-character version where row AA is after row Z, you can do this in 1.8.7 and newer:

```
row_num = row_string.bytes.inject(0) {|total, x| total = total * 26 + x - ?A + 1}
```

You may want to upcase your row string beforehand, just to be on the safe side.

In 1.8.6 and below, `String` does not have a `bytes` method.  You can accomplish the same thing by doing:

```
row_num = 0
row_string.each_byte {|x| row_num = row_num * 26 + x - ?A + 1}
```

Comment: I agree, a hash is the best way of dealing with this.

Comment: Many thanks indeed. Hashes are certainly the easiest way forward. However:

outs = {}
for seat in self.seats
 outs[seat.num][seat.row] = "yes"
end 
return outs

Produces The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]=. Both seat.row and seat.num have asserted values, so I'm guessing it must be a syntax error.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: It's not a syntax error, you just need to create the array for each row before trying to assign elements to it.  Try this:  outs = {}; for seat in self.seats; outs[seat.num] ||= []; outs[seat.num][seat.row] = "yes"; end  The "outs[seat.num] ||= []" line will set outs[seat.num] to be an empty array if it doesn't have a value yet.
Also, you might be better off using true instead of "yes".

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the solution I've come up with that seems to do the trick:

```
seat_array = Hash.new{|h,k| h[k]=Hash.new(&h.default_proc) }
for seat in self.seats
seat_array[seat.row.downcase][seat.num] = seat
end 
return seat_array
```

Many thanks to everyone for such quick and useful responses. I'll certainly be helping others with PHP!

Answer (score 1):

Well to get the index of a letter you could do something like this

```
('A'..'Z').to_a.index('C')
```

which would return 2

I notice in the array examples you gave you started A = 1 instead of 0.